# where is bootstrap link in asp.net template pages

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

(in vs 2015/asp.net/web forms template)there is several web pages like Register page and login page.all the elements on this pages is created with bootstrap , but I wondered there isn't any bootstrap link command in html source of this pages :

```
<%@ Page Title="Log in" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Login.aspx.vb" Inherits="Account_Login" Async="true" %>
```

### <%: Title %>.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <section id="loginForm">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <h4>Use a local account to log in.</h4>
                <hr />
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="ErrorMessage" Visible="false">
                    <p class="text-danger">
                        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="FailureText" />
                    </p>
                </asp:PlaceHolder>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">User name</asp:Label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserName" CssClass="form-control" />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName"
                            CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The user name field is required." />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">Password</asp:Label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Password" TextMode="Password" CssClass="form-control" />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The password field is required." />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="RememberMe" />
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="RememberMe">Remember me?</asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="LogIn" Text="Log in" CssClass="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>
                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="RegisterHyperLink" ViewStateMode="Disabled">Register</asp:HyperLink>
                if you don't have a local account.
            </p>
        </section>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <section id="socialLoginForm">
            <uc:openauthproviders runat="server" id="OpenAuthLogin" />
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

where can I find the bootstrap link command?

Comment: So do you want to refer bootstrap in your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HI Pooya as you can see this page is child page and all the links are define in master like bootstrap and js file

Child page - login.aspx
Master Page - site.master

so you can find all the link in site.master page